# HttpClient and Basic Auth in URL

Tags: .net, basic-authentication, dotnet-httpclient

I'd like to use `HttpClient` and HTTP basic auth by specifying username and password in the URL, like this:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 
    "https://username:password@example.com");

using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
    await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

However there is no `Authorization` header sent with the request.

Is there a way to tell HttpClient to support this, or do I have to manually fetch the credentials from the URL and set the headers myself?

Comment: `username:password` in the URL is a web browser feature. HttpClient won't move those to the header for you the way a browser will. Remove them from the URL and see Jamie Rees's answer.

Comment: @ToddMenier HTTP url specification does permit username:password combo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the header instead of passing it through the URL

```
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password1234");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```